# Speeding up my numpy code

Tags: performance, numpy, cython

I am learning cython. I wrote a numpy code:

```
from numpy import *

def set_onsite(n):
    a=linspace(0,n,n+1)
    onsite=zeros([n+1,n+1],float)
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        onsite[i,i]=a[i]*a[i]
    return onsite
```

and I used %timeit to calculate the time

```
%timeit ex5.set_onsite(10000)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop
```

So I wrote a cython version like this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

def set_onsite(np.int_t n):
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1,mode='c'] a=np.linspace(0,n,n+1)
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2,mode='c'] onsite=np.empty(n+1,n+1)
    cdef np.int_t i

    for i in range(0,n+1):
        onsite[i,i]=a[i]*a[i]
    return onsite
```

and this time the result is:

```
%timeit ex5.set_onsite(10000)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.1 ms per loop
```

the results are almost the same. I do not satisfy with this result, so I was wondering is there any way to make the code faster than 18.1 ms per loop?

Comment: You are still making calls to `numpy` functions, `linspace`, `empty`, `range` and indexing.  To get real speed you need use `nditer` to iterate, including generating `a`, and the initializing `onsite` array.

Comment: Your cython code doesn't produce the same thing does it?  You initial `onsite` with `empty`, so the off diagonal values can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

Cython is probably not the right tool to speed up your computations here.

The first thing you should keep in mind is that vectorizing can give you a huge speed boost. The idea is to convert explicit for-loops to operations on whole vectors.

This function does the same, but avoids the for loop:

```
def set_onsite_vec(n):
    a = np.linspace(0,n,n+1)
    diag = a*a
    return np.diag(diag)
```

`%timeit set_onsite(100)` -> `10000 loops, best of 3: 39 µs per loop`
`%timeit set_onsite_vec(100)` -> `10000 loops, best of 3: 16.3 µs per loop``

This gives you quite a boost, but you will notice that for larger arrays this gain will decrease.

The problem is that you are creating a huge matrix (`O(n^2)` entries) - this matrix has to be allocated and initialized, which is the bottleneck.

Note that the matrix only has only non-zero elements at the diagonal. You can use that information and create a sparse matrix instead.

```
from scipy.sparse import diags

def set_onsite_sparse(n):
    a = np.linspace(0,n,n+1)
    diag = a*a
    return diags([diag], [0])
```

`%timeit set_onsite_sparse(10000)` -> `1000 loops, best of 3: 119 µs per loop`

Not creating the dense matrix gives you a huge speed boost.

Of course you will only use that improvement if you do some other sparse manipulations before converting back to a dense matrix.

In short: You probably cannot improve significantly using Cython, yet using sparse linear algebra could give you a huge performance boost. But this depends on how you want to use this function in your program.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I think I might need to know something about vectorizing my code

Comment: 'vectorizing' in this context means learning which `numpy` operations operate (with compiled code) on whole vectors (e.g. `a`), and how they can be combined to produce 2d and larger arrays.